Unable to create Key Type element for the 'BearerKey'. This might be due to wrong version of MessageSecurityVersion set on the SecurityBindingElement
getting this error :  Unable to create Key Type element for the Key Type 'BearerKey'. This might be due to a wrong version of MessageSecurityVersion set on the SecurityBindingElement.
I am using this as my binding but getting error
Binding Class :
public class CustomFederatedBufferedBinding : WS2007FederationHttpBinding
{
    public CustomFederatedBufferedBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode mode) : base(mode)
    {
        Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = CoreWCF.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
        Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
        Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, BindingHelper.JWTCloseTimeout, 0);
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, BindingHelper.JWTSendTimeout, 0);
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, BindingHelper.JWTReceiveTimeout, 0);
        Name = "federated";
    }

    protected override TransportBindingElement GetTransport()
    {
        var httpBinding =  new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = BindingHelper.JWTMaxBufferPoolSize,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = BindingHelper.JWTMaxReceivedMessageSize,
        };
        //var hgfgh = this.MessageVersion;
        return httpBinding;
    }

    protected override SecurityBindingElement CreateMessageSecurity()
    {
        var sec = base.CreateMessageSecurity();
        //sec.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        sec.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        return sec;
    }

}

StartUp class :
namespace Demo
{
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Enable CoreWCF Services, with metadata (WSDL) support
        services.AddServiceModelServices()
            .AddServiceModelMetadata();
        
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       // new ServiceHost();
        app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
        {

                
                serviceBuilder.AddService<DemoService>();
                serviceBuilder.AddServiceEndpoint<DemoService, IDemoService>(new CustomFederatedBufferedBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), "/DemoService.svc");
                
                var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
           

        });
    }
}

}

Modifying the version of the code, I think you can try the following:

Security.Message.SecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;

At the same time, I have collected relevant information, and it is possible that this problem will occur if other security settings are not set up properly. Such as Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential and Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite.
